# Subtract 1 month from datetime column from database

Tags: mysql, datetime

I need a query which subtracts 1 month from the date stored in the `datetime` so that i can use it in google line chart.My query now is

```
$sql_query = "SELECT count(ip_address) AS count, 
                    DATE(visit_date_time) as visit_date_time 
            FROM db_views 
            WHERE user_id = $id 
            GROUP BY DATE(visit_date_time) 
            ORDER BY visit_date_time LIMIT 30 ";
```

Subtracting 1 month is like "0 for Jan", "1 for Feb"....., "11 for Dec".

I have used dateadd & datesub but didn't get the desired result and end up with errors.

**Update**

Here is the complete code.

```
$sql_query = "SELECT count(ip_address) AS count, DATE(visit_date_time) as visit_date_time, MONTH(DATE(visit_date_time)) - 1 mon FROM db_views WHERE user_id = '".$_SESSION[$mainfunctions->GetLoginSessionVar()]."' GROUP BY DATE(visit_date_time) ORDER BY visit_date_time LIMIT 30 ";
$result = mysqli_query($mainfunctions->connection,$sql_query);

echo "{ \"cols\": [ {\"id\":\"\",\"label\":\"Date\",\"pattern\":\"\",\"type\":\"date\"}, {\"id\":\"\",\"label\":\"Views\",\"pattern\":\"\",\"type\":\"number\"} ], \"rows\": [ ";
$total_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$row_num = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $row_num++;
    $vDate = str_replace("-", ",",$row['visit_date_time']);
    if ($row_num == $total_rows){
      echo "{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(".$vDate.")\",\"f\":null},{\"v\":" . $row['count'] . ",\"f\":null}]}";
    } else {
      echo "{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(".$vDate.")\",\"f\":null},{\"v\":" . $row['count'] . ",\"f\":null}]}, ";
    }
}
echo " ] }";
mysqli_close($mainfunctions->connection);
```

My Output : `{"v":"Date(2017,01,02)","f":null},{"v":6,"f":null}`

Desired Output : `{"v":"Date(2017,00,02)","f":null},{"v":6,"f":null}`

Comment: in sql we have this 

DATEADD(month, -1, DATE(visit_date_time))

Comment: ? Subtract 1 from which column ?

Comment: Put the result in a column called What?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Subtract 1 from visit_date_time column. Actually js of google line chart reads month 0 as Jan and 11 as Dec Thats why I need this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MONTH` function to extract the month from the datetime (probably `visit_date_time` in your case) and subtract 1 from it.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(ip_address) AS count,
    DATE(visit_date_time) AS visit_date_time,
    MONTH(DATE(visit_date_time)) - 1 mon
FROM
    db_views
WHERE
    user_id = $id
GROUP BY DATE(visit_date_time)
ORDER BY visit_date_time
LIMIT 30
```

Comment: Getting the same result @GurV. I need to call the visit_date_time to display the dates & i am getting the same result.

Comment: @Prateek well what is your sample input data and expected output? Please post it as a textual table in the question

Answer (score 1):

You can use this in your query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2017-01-21 12:36:32','%m') -1;
```

Result: 0

**sample**

to get get number of month starting with 0. month_number 1 and 2 are gives the same result

```
$sql_query = "SELECT count(ip_address) AS count, 
               DATE(visit_date_time) as visit_date_time,
               MONTH(visit_date_time) as month_number_1,
               DATE_FORMAT(visit_date_time,'%m') -1 as month_number_2
            FROM db_views 
            WHERE user_id = $id 
            GROUP BY DATE(visit_date_time) 
            ORDER BY visit_date_time LIMIT 30 ";
```

Comment: I need the subtracted date for displaying it in the chart. how can i use this query.

Comment: @Prateek - i have add a sample in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Didn't found any proper solution in mysql. So I'm using php code to get the desired output. Here is the code used to subtract 1 month

```
$vDate = str_replace("-","",$row['visit_date_time'])-100;
$vDate = substr_replace($vDate,",",6,0);
$vDate = substr_replace($vDate,",",4,0);
```

If there is any solution in mysql . please let me know.